# how do i substitute the original coco dataset for the MindRecord?

Tags: python, deep-learning

I'm trying to train a SSD model on coco2017, following a [tutorial](https://www.mindspore.cn/tutorials/application/en/r2.1/cv/ssd.html) that loads dataset from a special format called MindRecord

```
mindrecord_dir = "./datasets/MindRecord_COCO"
mindrecord_file = "./datasets/MindRecord_COCO/ssd.mindrecord0"

dataset = create_ssd_dataset(mindrecord_file, batch_size=5, rank=0, use_multiprocessing=True)
```

and this is just a tiny part of the original coco dataset

```
def create_ssd_dataset(mindrecord_file, batch_size=32, device_num=1, rank=0,
                       is_training=True, num_parallel_workers=1, use_multiprocessing=True):
    """Create SSD dataset with MindDataset."""
    dataset = MindDataset(mindrecord_file, columns_list=["img_id", "image", "annotation"], num_shards=device_num,
                          shard_id=rank, num_parallel_workers=num_parallel_workers, shuffle=is_training)

    decode = Decode()
    dataset = dataset.map(operations=decode, input_columns=["image"])

    change_swap_op = HWC2CHW()
    # Computed from random subset of ImageNet training images
    normalize_op = Normalize(mean=[0.485 * 255, 0.456 * 255, 0.406 * 255],
                             std=[0.229 * 255, 0.224 * 255, 0.225 * 255])
    color_adjust_op = RandomColorAdjust(brightness=0.4, contrast=0.4, saturation=0.4)
    compose_map_func = (lambda img_id, image, annotation: preprocess_fn(img_id, image, annotation, is_training))

    if is_training:
        output_columns = ["image", "box", "label", "num_match"]
        trans = [color_adjust_op, normalize_op, change_swap_op]
    else:
        output_columns = ["img_id", "image", "image_shape"]
        trans = [normalize_op, change_swap_op]

    dataset = dataset.map(operations=compose_map_func, input_columns=["img_id", "image", "annotation"],
                          output_columns=output_columns, python_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
                          num_parallel_workers=num_parallel_workers)

    dataset = dataset.map(operations=trans, input_columns=["image"], python_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing,
                          num_parallel_workers=num_parallel_workers)

    dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size, drop_remainder=True)
    return dataset
```

i've already downloaded the original coco dataset

```
COCOdataset2017
├── annotations
│   ├── captions_train2017.json
│   ├── captions_val2017.json
│   ├── instances_train.json
│   ├── instances_val.json
│   ├── person_keypoints_train2017.json
│   └── person_keypoints_val2017.json
└── images
    ├── train2017
    └── val2017
```

how do i substitute the original coco dataset for the MindRecord part and still use the rest (model definition and the related part) of the tutorial?